# Obter os valore de uma nova linha num gráfico

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma folha Excel em que todos os dias acrescento uma nova linha com os valores da cotação Brent e outros indicadores. Esses mesmo valores depois são atualizados num gráfico de linhas.

Acontece que sempre que adiciono uma linha nova, os valores da mesma não são inseridos no gráfico por não fazerem parte do *range* da formula no gráfico.

Há alguma forma de ir buscar a informação da nova linha automaticamente sem ter que reconfigurar o gráfico para o novo *range*?

Esta fórmula está inserida no gráfico

```
=Energias!$A$1:$C$417;Energias!$J$1:$Q$417;Energias!$T$1:$V$417
```

Quando adiciono uma linha nova a fórmula do gráfico fica assim:

```
=Energias!$A$1:$C$1;Energias!$A$3:$C$418;Energias!$J$1:$Q$1;Energias!$J$3:$Q$418;Energias!$T$1:$V$1;Energias!$T$3:$V$418
```

Comment: Não compreendi muito bem. Favor criar um [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Olá

Você pode criar um Range com desloc.

Suponhamos que você tenha a situação abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode criar um campo através do gerenciador de nomes

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando a formula

=DESLOC(Planilha1!$A$2;0;0;CONT.NÚM(Planilha1!$A:$A);1)

Aí é só colocar o nome pelo qual optou no meu caso usei "Teste" na serie que você quer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O gráfico a seguir ficou dinâmico. Cada valor digitado na coluna A será automaticamente replicado para o gráfico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]